# Diagonal morphism of henselization is an open immersion?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring, denote by $R \rightarrow R^h$ its henselization. Write $S = \operatorname{Spec} R$ and $S^h = \operatorname{Spec} R^h$. Is it true that the diagonal morphism $\Delta \colon S^h \rightarrow S^h \times_S S^h$ is an open immersion? I am reading the chapter by Orgogozo and Vidal in ["Courbes semi-stables et groupe fondamental en geometrie algebrique"](https://link.springer.com/book/9783764363086), where this is used (without proof) in the proof of Lemme 5.4.

I have tried the following. Write
$$R^h = \varinjlim_{(A,\mathfrak{q})} A,$$
with the limit running over the pairs $(A,\mathfrak{q})$, where $A$ is an étale algebra over $R$, and $\mathfrak{q} \in \operatorname{Spec} A$ is such that $\kappa(\mathfrak{q}) = R/\mathfrak{m}$ ([TAG 04GN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04GN)). Then
$$ S = \varprojlim_{(A,\mathfrak{q})} \operatorname{Spec} A,$$
and
$$S^h \times_S S^h = (\varprojlim_{(A,\mathfrak{q})} \operatorname{Spec} A) \times_R (\varprojlim_{(A,\mathfrak{q})} \operatorname{Spec} A) = \varprojlim_{(A,\mathfrak{q})} (\operatorname{Spec} A \times_R \operatorname{Spec} A).$$
Now the diagonal morphism $\Delta \colon S^h \rightarrow S^h \times_S S^h$ is the $\varprojlim$ of the individual diagonal morphisms $\operatorname{Spec} A \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A \times_R \operatorname{Spec} A$. Each of them is an open immersion, because $A$ is étale over $R$, in particular, $A$ is unramified over $R$, and hence we can apply [TAG 02GE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GE). Can I somehow deduce from this that $\Delta$ is itself an open immersion? I tried to apply the theory in EGA IV.3, Section 8, but it is not obvious to me how the setup there is applicable to this problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I didn’t check details, but it seems like it might be possible to show directly from the generators-and-relations definition of Kahler differentials that the colimit of unramified ring morphisms is unramified.

Comment: Hmm, this seems fishy to me. What is easy is that $S^h \to S$ is weakly étale \[Tag [092N](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/092N)\(3\)\], so in particular formally unramified \[Tag [092M](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/092M)\]. So $\Delta$ is a closed immersion whose ideal $I$ is pure \[Tag [04PQ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04PQ)\]. Such a thing is an open immersion if and only if $I$ is finitely generated \[Tag [05KK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05KK)\], but I don't think that is satisfied in this case.

Comment: An enlightening (but different) example to think about is a Galois field extension $k \to \ell$ with profinite Galois group $G$. Then $\operatorname{Spec} \ell \times_{\operatorname{Spec} k} \operatorname{Spec} \ell$ is isomorphic to $G$ copies of $\operatorname{Spec} \ell$, so the diagonal is an open immersion if and only if $G$ is finite. But this doesn't quite apply here, as the function field extension $k(S) \to k(S^h)$ (say if $S$ is a curve over a field $k$) is not Galois.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Hey Remy, 
I am currently playing around with the following. Let $R = k[x]_{(x)}$, with $k$ is algebraically closed. Then $R^h$ is the algebraic closure of $R$ in $k[[x]] = \widehat{R}$. Looking at elements like $(x + 1)^{1/k} \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes (x + 1)^{1/k}$, for $k$ a positive integer, in the kernel of the diagonal map $R^h \otimes_R R^h \rightarrow R^h$, I cannot imagine this kernel is finitely generated. But this looks difficult to show.

Comment: If $I$ is the kernel of the map $R^h \otimes_R R^h \rightarrow R^h$, then $I/I^2$ is the module of differentials of $R^h/R$, which is $0$. Hence if $I$ is not $0$, it can not be finitely generated. But it seems clear that $(x + 1)^{1/2} \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes (x + 1)^{1/2}$ is not $0$.

Comment: @Angelo I am not sure I understand your argument. Why should $I = I^2$ and $I \neq 0$ imply that $I$ is not finitely generated? In an arbitrary ring, this is not true.

Comment: @Angelo an idempotent ideal $I$ is finitely generated if and only if it is generated by an idempotent, but not necessarily by $0$.

Comment: Yes, of course I knew that. I can't believe that I said something this moronic. I had an idea in mind which goes beyond the stupidity of what I wrote; if I can make it work I'll post it, hoping not to embarrass myself again :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.

[As pointed out by R. van Dobben de Bruyn in the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461206/diagonal-morphism-of-henselization-is-an-open-immersion#comment1196216_461206), $\Delta$ is an open immersion if and only if its ideal $\operatorname{ker}( R^h \otimes_R R^h \to R^h)$ is finitely generated.

Since $R^h$ is the filtered colimit of the $A \otimes_R A$ for $A$ pointed étale algebras over $R$, any finite set of generators must be contained in some $A \otimes_R A$ and thus in $\operatorname{ker}(A \otimes_R A \to A)$.

Since every element of $\operatorname{ker}(A \otimes_R A \to A)$, when sent to $R^h \otimes_R R^h$, certainly lies in $\operatorname{ker}( R^h \otimes_R R^h \to R^h)$, if the kernel is generated by elements of $A$ then in fact

$$\operatorname{ker}( R^h \otimes_R R^h \to R^h) = \operatorname{ker}(A \otimes_R A \to A) \otimes_{ (A \otimes_R A)} (R^h \otimes_R R^h)$$

which implies

$$ (R^h \otimes_R R^h) \otimes_{(A \otimes_R A)} A = R^h.$$

The left hand side is the colimit over pointed étale algebras  $B$ over $A$ of $(B\otimes_R B) \otimes_{ (A \otimes_R A)} A = B\otimes_A B$ and thus is $A^h \otimes_A A^h$. Since $A^h$ is $R^h$, this is saying that $A^h \otimes_A A^h = A^h$, which is absurd unless $A = A^h$, for example by restricting to the generic point and noting that this map is never an isomorphism for any nontrivial algebra over a field.

So this only happens if some finitely generated étale algebra over $R$ is already Henselian, which does not happen in the case of interested.

(This was partially inspired by the [strategy of Angelo in the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461206/diagonal-morphism-of-henselization-is-an-open-immersion#comment1197413_461206).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Will! The algebra $A$ need not be a local ring of course, so I guess by $A^h$ you mean the henselization of the pair $(A,\mathfrak{q})$ where $\mathfrak{q}$ is the basepoint of $A$ over $\mathfrak{m}$?

Comment: @HugoZock Yes, exactly.